# How do i display a FormArray of GroupLists?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to make an interactive form that on each row lists an item together with a remove button (called verwijderen in my example). These items are retrieved from the database and each instantiated as a custom object called `LaborPeriod`.

These objects are then transformed into `FormGroup` object and then added to a `FormArray`. The definition of this formgroup is the following:

```
  let formGroup = this.fb.group({
    id: this.account.laborperiods[i].id,
    beginDate: this.account.laborperiods[i].beginDate,
    endDate: this.account.laborperiods[i].endDate,
    hours: this.account.laborperiods[i].hours,
    account: this.account.laborperiods[i].account
  })
  if(!this.laborPeriodArray){
    this.laborPeriodArray = new FormArray([])
  }
  this.laborPeriodArray.push(formGroup)
}
```

The definition of the laborPeriodArray in the main FormGroup is also laborPeriodArray. The main FormGroup looks like the following:

```
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router,
              private accountService: AccountService) {
    this.title = "Account aanpassen";
    //console.log(this.account.enabled + " : " + this.account.role)
    this.accountUpdateForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [''],
      username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      status: '',
      permission:'',
      laborPeriodArray:this.fb.array([])
    });
  }
```

The entire component looks like this: Here you can see that laborPeriodArray gets initialized in the onInit method.

```
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router,
              private accountService: AccountService) {
    this.title = "Account aanpassen";
    //console.log(this.account.enabled + " : " + this.account.role)
    this.accountUpdateForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [''],
      username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      status: '',
      permission:'',
      laborPeriodArray:this.fb.array([])
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let formGroupArray: FormGroup[] = [];
    this.route.paramMap
      .switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
        this.accountService.getAccount(params.get("id")))
      .subscribe(account => {
        this.account = account;
        for(let i=0; i < account.laborperiods.length; i++){
          let formGroup = this.fb.group({
            id: this.account.laborperiods[i].id,
            beginDate: this.account.laborperiods[i].beginDate,
            endDate: this.account.laborperiods[i].endDate,
            hours: this.account.laborperiods[i].hours,
            account: this.account.laborperiods[i].account
          })
          if(!this.laborPeriodArray){
            this.laborPeriodArray = new FormArray([])
          }
          this.laborPeriodArray.push(formGroup)
        }
        console.log("laborPeriod" + JSON.stringify(this.laborPeriodArray.length))

        this.ngOnChanges();
      });
  }

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    if (this.account !== undefined) {
      this.accountUpdateForm.reset({
        name: this.account.name,
        username: this.account.username,
        status: this.account.enabled,
        permission: this.account.admin,
        laborPeriodArray: this.laborPeriodArray
      });
    }
  }
```

All the FormGroup items are added but not displayed. The rows are blank. This is the relevant snippet from my HTML page

```
<table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Begin datum</th>
        <th>Eind datum</th>
        <th>Aantal uren</th>
        <th>Actie</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr formArrayName="laborPeriodArray" *ngFor = "let laborperiod of laborPeriodArray.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
        <td formControlName="beginDate">{{laborperiod.value.get('beginDate') | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
        <td formControlName="endDate">{{laborperiod.value.get('endDate') | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
        <td formControlName="hours">{{laborperiod.value.get('hours')}}</td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          Verwijderen
        </button>
      </tr>
```

This is giving me the browser error `ERROR Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute` but I am specifying the formControlName for each td row. So I don't understand what is causing the error. Furthermore I would also like to know how I can link the Remove button to the data corresponding to each row. I take it I have to use the index I for this but i'm not sure.

EDIT:

After applying AJT_82's solution I still don't have it working. It appears to have something to do with the database retrieved data itself. When I add the example account array of AJT_82 to my ngOnInit() like so:

```
  account1 = { laborperiods: [{ id: 1, hours:11 }, { id: 2, hours:22 }, { id: 3, hours:33 }] }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap
      .switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
        this.accountService.getAccount(params.get("id")))
      .subscribe(account => {
        this.account = account;
        for(let i=0; i < account.laborperiods.length; i++){
          let formGroup = this.fb.group({
            id: this.account1.laborperiods[i].id,
            beginDate: this.account.laborperiods[i].beginDate,
            endDate: this.account.laborperiods[i].endDate,
            hours: this.account1.laborperiods[i].hours,
            account: this.account.laborperiods[i].account
          })
          this.laborPeriodArray.push(formGroup)
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(account.laborperiods[0].beginDate))
        this.ngOnChanges();
      });
  }
```

it works but it shows only 3 rows. That's the total length of the example account array.

This is the account class:

```
export class Account {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  name: string;
  enabled: boolean
  password: string;
  person: Person;
  admin: boolean;
  laborperiods: LaborPeriod[]
  remainingLeaveHours:number;
}
```

and this is the LaborPeriod class:

```
export class LaborPeriod{
    id: number
    beginDate: Date
    endDate: Date
    hours: number
    account: Account
}
```

Is there anything wrong with its field declarations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot have `formArrayName` on the same element as your iteration and `formGroupName`, you need to move the `formArrayName` to an upper level. Also I see no use of the `formControlName`, as these are not editable fields, and Angular will throw error for this. Also the use of for example...

```
{{laborperiod.value.get('beginDate') | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```

is incorrect, it should be just

```
{{laborperiod.value.beginDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```

Assumingly in your code, the variable `laberPeriodArray` is declared...

```
this.laborPeriodArray = 
     this.accountUpdateForm.controls.laborPeriodArray as FormArray
```

since you are referring to `this.laborPeriodArray` in your code, therefore the following:

```
if(!this.laborPeriodArray){
  this.laborPeriodArray = new FormArray([])
}
```

is redundant, you have already declared it in the build of the form as an empty FormArray. But that is just a sidenote :)

All in all, your template should look something like this:

```
<table formArrayName="laborPeriodArray" >
  <tr *ngFor="let laborperiod of laborPeriodArray.controls; 
      let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
    <td>{{laborperiod.value.hours}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qhxw2w?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: thank you for you demo, it works in your demo but when I apply everything you have shown I still don't see any data appearing. All I see is 11 empty rows. When I use your example laborperiod array on my id and hours fields then it works, but it only shows 3 rows in the table, that's the same length as your example array. Please look at the edit in my first post for further explanation

Comment: the only difference between your dataset and mine is that yours is hardcoded and mine is retrieved from the database. One might think that something goes wrong when retrieving but that doesen't seem the case because I am able to display the entire LaborRecord array content as a Jsonstring in the console

Comment: Well that's not the only difference, as mentioned in answer, your template has errors, for example should be `{{laborperiod.value.hours}}`. And it doesn't matter if this is hardcoded data or not. If you are receiving data correctly and are setting the values from inside subscribe like you seem to be doing, it should work just fine :) If not, please create a demo that showcases the current behavior :)

Comment: well I've solved the problem... The problem had to do with the accountUpdateForm reset method call in the ngOnChanges method. Not sure what this method does, I'm building a project that I diden't start plus i'm relatively new to Angular haha. Next time I should first check what everything does I suppose. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
laborperiod.value.get('beginDate')
```

By

```
laborperiod.value['beginDate']
```

I also recommande that you FormGroup variable to be a Class attribute and not a OnInit() one.

I also recommande using ReactiveForms with it's API FormControls.

- Let me know what happened

Comment: changing it to value['beginDate'] has no effect. I will research ReactiveForms